# Cannot import MSTL from statsmodels

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I am currently trying to import MSTL from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal the module of MSTL (https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.MSTL.html) but it returns an ImportError. I have installed statsmodels from conda on MAC M1 2020

Comment: You need to use the un-released verion. This requires installing from git hub.  Something like pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had the same issue and did some research.
It seems that MSTL is only available on the most recent version of statsmodels: version 0.14.0

If you install statsmodels using `conda install -c conda-forge statsmodels`,
you will get the statsmodels 0.13.2 version.

(Using a script editor, try searching for 'MSTL' through C:\Users{username}\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels, or wherever statsmodels is installed on your machine, you will probably not find it)

You'll need to install the most recent version from the latest source on statsmodels's github repository:
[www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html)

From the anaconda prompt:

`git clone https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git`
`pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels`

You will need a C compiler and git installed
For git you can use: `conda install -c anaconda git`

Be careful as the installation of the newest version may interfere with your other installed python packages.
I would recommend that you use a conda virtual environment for this.